# Weird problem with `renderDataTable` and `renderUI` with different orders

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I'm working on a shiny app and trying to use `renderDataTable` and `renderUI` on the same page. The following codes work fine. But when I switch the order of `2. render select input` and `3. render data table`, it seems `input$selected_variable` cannot reflect what is selected on the shiny app. Neither the `print(input$selected_variable)` can print the selected value in the terminal, nor the `textOutput` can show the selected value on the app interface. Does anyone know why this may happen? Another follow-up question is that if I remove `filter = 'top'` in the `renderDataTable`, this issue won't occur either no matter which order is applied. Does this problem has anything to do with the `filter = 'top'`? (This `filter = 'top'` option in `dataTable` seemed also cause a few other weird behaviors when I tried out some other shiny app designs.)

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  shinyApp(
    ### ui
    ui = fluidPage(
      fileInput('input_data_file', 
                        label = "Load input data file(s)",
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         buttonLabel = "Browse or Drop...",
                         placeholder = "(multiple) csv file(s)"),
      dataTableOutput('input_table'),
      uiOutput('params'),
      verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = T),
      plotlyOutput('plot')
    ),
    
    ### server
    server = function(input, output) {
      ### values placeholder
      values <- reactiveValues()
      values$data <- NULL
      
      ### 1. upload data file
      observeEvent(input$input_data_file, {
        req(input$input_data_file)
        file <- input$input_data_file
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
        req(file)
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))

        values$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      })
        
      ### 2. render select input
      output$params <- renderUI({
        fluidRow(column(6, selectInput("selected_variable", "Variable:",
                                       choices = setdiff(names(values$data), 'CustomerID')
                                       )))
        })


      ### 3. render data table
       output$input_table <- DT::renderDataTable(
            values$data,
            filter = 'top', # removing this line can also solve the issue
            options = list(scrollX=TRUE, scrollCollapse=TRUE, stateSave = TRUE, search = list(regex = TRUE)),
            server = FALSE)

      ### 4. render text output 
      observe({
         #req(input$selected_variable)
         print(input$selected_variable)
         output$text <-renderText({input$selected_variable})
       })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @Limey, thanks for answering this! The code above works fine. But if you more the chunk below `### 3. render data table` in front of the chunk below `### 2. render select input`, the `textOutput` cannot display anything.

Comment: That's what I did.  I saw no change in behaviour.  Hence: unable to reproduce.